# Selecting two elements from array

Tags: ruby

In my application I need to select element from array by condition and the previous one. I'm using `each_cons` method, so my code looks like:

```
range_to = 2500

points = [
  {alti: 3000, time: 1},
  {alti: 2000, time: 2},
  ...
]

points.each_cons(2) do |pair|
  if pair.last[:alti] <= range_to
    new_point = Interpolation.find_between(pair.first, pair.last, range_to) 
  end
  break if new_point
end
```

`Interpolation.find_between` makes interpolation and returns point that lays between two in arguments, like:

```
{alti: 2500, time 1.5}
```

Is there any more right/elegant approach?

Comment: Given that you are enumerating each adjacent pair in the array, `each_cons` is the correct tool for the job.

Comment: What are `@points`, `@range_to`, `Interpolation`, `find_between`?

Comment: @sawa, I improved my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [Pepegasca answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29810033/1044162) I came to this solution:

```
pair = 
  points.each_cons(2).detect do |pair| 
    range_to.between? pair.last[:alti], pair.first[:alti]
  end

return nil unless pair

Interpolation.find_between(pair.first, pair.last, range_to)
```

I think it's simple, clear and follow ruby style guide.

`points.each_cons(2)` without block given returns `Enumerator`, then `detect` finds first by given in block condition. Then condition to check if it was successful and if yes - function `Interpolation.find_between` do its work and returns value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like:

```
selected_points = points.each_cons(2).select{|p| p.last[:alti] <= range_to}.first
selected_points && new_point = Interpolation.find_between(selected_points.first, selected_points.last, range_to)
```

Comment: Like your solution, but better to use `detect` instead `select{ }.first`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure each_cons here make things clearer. Why no just do this?

```
upper = points.find_index{|point| point[:alti] <= range }
lower = upper - 1
new_point = Interpolation.find_between(points[lower], points[upper], range_to)
```

Comment: It will cause additional conditions. In example if upper will be first element.